# Excel - Invalid Date cast (year before 1900)

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, oracle11g

I need to export data into Excel, but unfortunally from Oracle table where inserts happen via Web apps. There are many typo mistakes created by end users (probably bad app designs), and most common mistakes are wrongly inserted dates. One of them is '16.03.0219', which is valid date so Insert occurs, but Date as you see is before year 1900.

When I try to convert this Date It fails, using every methods I encountered (FromOADate, ToOADate, DateTime.ParseExact, Convert.ToDateTime etc.).

**How can I convert this to a Date valid for insert into Excel ?**

My current conversion is like this:

```
((DateTime)my_date).ToOADate().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This succesfully converts all dates until It bumps into that Date mistakes. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: _"When I try to convert this Date It fails"_ - but `DateTime.Parse("16.03.0219")` has no problem parsing that date.

Comment: Do a find/replace on that column for anything less than 1900 and replace with 1900...

Comment: @stuartd, I will try that ASAP, didn't try that so far.

Comment: @stuartd, maybe parsing works but there is still an error when I try to insert that into Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike, maybe a short example ? I think this is a case.

Comment: @Lucy82 The find/replace is in the edit menu - good for tricks like this often.

Comment: @SolarMike, what edit menu are you talking about, in Excel ? I need to convert date in C# code, before I export data into Excel.

Comment: @Lucy82 Yes, in excel, you tagged excel so I assumed you are familiar with it.

Comment: @SolarMike, sure I am fammiliar with It, I'll take a look. Though Excel language translation is horrible in my native language :)

Comment: _"there is still an error when I try to insert that into Excel"_ yes, because you have invalid data, which needs to be corrected before inserting into Excel. Your choices are a) write rules to convert the invalid data or b) flag up the invalid data for manual correction.

Comment: Perhaps consider data validation for the app the users use to enter data... But that may not be in the OP's control...

Comment: @stuartd, I guess I wasn't clear on qeustion, so I edited now a bit.

Comment: @SolarMike, unfortunally I don't have any influence on that. End users  enters dates via web apps, and some of them might be just plug-ins for desktop apps. All apps are beyond our reach - we are just collectors of all data...Bump

Comment: Excel cannot handle dates before the year 1900. Not at all. Either fix the dates before you export them to Excel, or save them as a string. And please describe what "fails" mean? Does the C# code fail to compile? Does the C# conversion code crash? Does the C# export code crash?

Comment: @Codo, yes C# code fails, different errors. One of them is "Not a legal OleAut Date". About fixing dates - If I do that, then data is not going to be same as It Is in DB. About saving as string - that results in cell being formatted as General, I tried that allready, and It works. Strangely, when e.g. you manually set some column in Excel to Date format, you can enter a Date like '16.03.0219' without any errors. That Is what I'm after, maybe It's possible.

Comment: If you set a cell in Excel to have a date format, you can also enter "abc* without error. The format is only applied if it's a valid date. But neither "abc" nor "16.03.0219" are valid dates for Excel. Going with strings for invalid dates is the only option I can see.

Comment: @Codo, you are right. I tried almost everything without luck. But what I did was to leave date format and insert string into cell. Strangely It works. You may provide an answer about this  If you wish and I'll accept It. Thanks for response.